# Load icons based on screen resolution

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I load icons based on the screen resolution in Android?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer Google's own [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) document to get your job done easily.